# Как закрыть сообщения бота от него же?(Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Проблема заключается в логировании сервера.При выводе всего добра в отдельный канал(и не только в отдельный канал), бот видя свое сообщение начинает спамить своим ником:[image: Скрин этого добра]

[image: Вот сам код]

Comment: Во-первых, пожалуйста, не размещайте код картинкой, его невозможно скопировать, во-вторых, вот код из документации 
`if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')`
Кажется, вам нужна проверка на автора

Comment: Просто долго не доходило как это сделать(.Извиняюсь за плохое оформление темы,а если кому интересно как я решил эту проблему - вот код:'@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(-)#айди канала для логов
    role = message.guild.get_role(-)#айди роли для фильтрации сообщений от бота
    if role in message.author.roles:
        print("")#заглушка 
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = message.author,
            description = message.content
        )
        await channel.send(embed=embed)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать проверку на пользователя, если это бот - не логируем

Достаточно добавить этот код в начале функции on_message.
Тогда бот просто не будет обрабатывать свои сообщения

```py
if message.author.id == client.user.id:
    return
```

Или так, тогда он просто не будет их отправлять

```py
if message.author.id != client.user.id:
    *тут код для лога*

тут остальное
```